# R: gplots, barplots: how to fix bar width independent of paper setting?

Tags: r, graph

I use the gplots package to output barplots. I use it inside a for-loop, so rest of the code is omitted to make it more clear:

```
library("gplots")
pdf(file = "/Users/Tim/desktop/pgax.pdf", onefile = TRUE, paper = "special")
par(mfrow = c(4,2)) #figures arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns
par(las=2) #perpendicular labels on x-axis

barplot2(expression,ylab = expression(expression),main = graph.header, cex.names =0.85, beside = TRUE, offset = 0, xpd = FALSE,axis.lty = 0, cex.axis = 0.85, plot.ci = TRUE,ci.l = expression - sd.value, ci.u = expression + sd.value, col = colors,width = 1,names.arg = c(etc))
```

Now when I specify the papersize at a4, and print out in two columns the bars are made so they fill up the full space assigned. If I only have a few bars in each graws, the width is too big compared to the height. I know I should be using `xlimit and width` = amongst and perhaps even the aspect ratio?, but I can't get the results I wanted. And unconvenient way is to specify the height and width output of the paper, and manually I adjust it for the number of bars in the plots each time. But this doesnt seem appropiate. Does someone know a convenient way to fix width bars in my plots?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although bar plots with wide bars can look silly, a wide bar plot with a few narrow bars in it will likely look even sillier.  That leaves you specifying the width of the plot (via the `width` argument to `pdf`).

It may be prettiest to keep all your plots the same size, in which case you just give `width` a fixed value.  If you do want narrower plots when there are less bars, you need a line of code like

```
plot_width <- 3 + 0.5 * nlevels(x_variable)
```